# PNG image opacity not working in browser

Tags: background, web, png, photoshop

As you can see here the screenshot in photoshop:

[image]

After I save it for web, using PNG-24 format this is how it looks like on my website:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFU2y.png]

Why isn't the image opacity working on my browser? Using firefox.

Actual PNG :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bggJC.png]

Comment: If you load your PNG24 image in Photoshop, will it still have 50% opacity? From the meaning of "24", it seems either there's no opacity or 1 bit of opacity.

Comment: @Vesper When I load it in Photoshop, it still have 50% opacity. Not sure what's the problem though.

Comment: Are you sure that the reason it seems to not be working is because you have a solid color behind it? Can you try putting some sort of pattern as the background for the containing element?

Comment: Can you embed the actual PNG in your question?

Comment: Embedded in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what your desired effect is, but I think that you want the gradient to disappear at the bottom. With that assumption, the problem with your gradient is that it fades from your brown color at the top to white at the bottom.

Your gradient looks something like this:

[image]

You want to change the color on both sides of the gradient to be the same brown color, then reduce the opacity of the right-hand side to 0%, like this:

[image]

I've adjusted it for you already, so here it is:

[image]

It doesn't look any different on a white background, but when it is on another color or texture you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Does your Photoshop layer have some effected added to it? I.e multiply etc. That would mean the layer is dependant and effected by what is below it.

Comment: Also make sure transparency is checked when you do "export for web"

Comment: No, it doesn't. And yes, transparency is checked. It's weird o.O

Comment: colour mode? RGB/CMYK settings?

Answer (score 0):

I face same kind of problem long years ago. when we save our file or image for web. it should be **save as web** & when we save in PNG format make sure that all background layers off. then just save as web & select PNG(24) from setting option.

& Yes Make sure that where you past the image in web must have CSS in the tag.

`background-color:none;`